# Browser extension for AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, browser

I'm looking for browser extension (for Firefox or Google Chrome) that allow me to make AJAX calls. I'd like to specify:

- Method (POST/PUT/GET/DELETE)
- URL
- Data to send (JSON/XML)

I know that I can make AJAX call from console, but it's nice to have dedicated tab for that.

Comment: Did you mean "HTTP requests" by "AJAX calls"?

Comment: You can quickly create your own extensions that can do this using Crossrider (check the appAPI.request() method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found 2 nice extensions:

- cREST Client - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/baedhhmoaooldchehjhlpppaieoglhml
- XHR POSTER - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akdbimilobjkfhgamdhneckaifceicen